# Loop the object returned from node promise and feed to the next .then

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've been stuck with this problem for what seems to be an eternity.
I'm just getting into node, and starting to get my head around promises etc.

What I am trying to do is fetch data from the Spotify API, and the first thing I do is getting my own playlists:

```
function getPlaylists(access_token) {

    var options = {
      url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists',
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
      json: true
    };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
        var playlists = body.items;
        var playlistArray = [];
        playlists.forEach(function(playlist) {
          var name = playlist.name;
          var url = playlist.tracks.href;

          playlistArray.push(url);
        });

        if(!error) {
          resolve(playlistArray);
        } else {
          reject(error);
        }

    });

  });
}
```

All right, so far so good. Now I also want to fetch the artists from these playlists:

```
function getArtists(url,access_token) {

  var params = {
    url: url,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
    json: true
  };

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    request.get(params, function(error, response, body) {

        var tracks = body.items;
        var artistArray = [];
        tracks.forEach(function(artists) {
          let allArtists = artists.track.artists;
          allArtists.forEach(function(artist) {
              artistArray.push(artist);
          });
        })

        if(!error) {
          resolve(artistArray);
        } else {
          reject(error);
        }

    });

  })

}
```

The way I return all of this data is:

```
getPlaylists(access_token)
     .then(function(playlists) {

       playlists.forEach(function(playlist) {
          getArtists(playlist,access_token)
               .then(function(artist) {
                    return artist;
               });
     });


     }).then(function(artists) {
        console.log("getting artists",artists);
     }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
})
```

However, this returns undefined. I can only make it work if I pass in a single playlist url to the getArtists function - the problem is the forEach loop which I don't know how to handle.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You forEach is not promise, as such your not returning a promise either.  If you using Bluebird promises, it has a Promise.map.  Replace your forEach with this, and make sure you return such Promise.map, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Weirdly enough, after reading a ton on promises, your code examples finally made it click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `[].map()` and `Promise.all()` to make a Promise that waits for the completion of an array of actions:

```
getPlaylists(access_token)
  .then(playlists => Promise.all(playlists.map(playlist => 
    getArtists(playlist, access_token)))
  .then(artists => {
    // use here
  });
```

Remember, for Promises to chain you must *return* a value or a Promise from your `.then()` handler. `.forEach()` always returns `undefined`, no matter what.

First, we turn the array of playlist into an array of Promises by using `.map()` with `getArtist`, then we pass that array of Promises to `Promise.all()`, which returns **a single Promise** which resolves when all Promises in the array resolve (or rejects when the first rejects).