# Return data from node promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently trying to fetch data from the Spotify API with promises, and yesterday I got tremendous help for another question, regarding the same topic: "[Loop the object returned from node promise and feed to the next .then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800325/loop-the-object-returned-from-node-promise-and-feed-to-the-next-then)".

What I do is first getting the tracks from my playlist, and then call another api which fetches the artists. Lastly I call another api which gets the artist images.
Now my question is: how do I return the data that I get from my promises?

This is my function that gets the playlist urls:

```
function getPlaylists(access_token) {

    var options = {
      url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists',
      headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
      json: true
    };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
        var playlists = body.items;
        var playlistArray = [];
        playlists.forEach(function(playlist) {
          var name = playlist.name;
          var url = playlist.tracks.href;

          playlistArray.push(url);
        });

        if(!error) {
          resolve(playlistArray);
        } else {
          reject(error);
        }

    });

  });
}
```

This one gets the artists:

```
function getArtists(url,access_token) {

  var params = {
    url: url,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
    json: true
  };

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    request.get(params, function(error, response, body) {

        var tracks = body.items;
        var artistArray = [];
        tracks.forEach(function(artists) {
          let allArtists = artists.track.artists;
          allArtists.forEach(function(artist) {
              artistArray.push(artist);
          });
        })

        if(!error) {
          resolve(artistArray);
        } else {
          reject(error);
        }

    });

  })

}
```

And this one gets the artist image:

```
function getArtistImages(artistId) {
    var options = {
      url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + artistId,
      json: true
    };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          if(error != null) {
              reject(error);
          } else {
              resolve(body);
          }
      });
    })

}
```

**EDIT EDIT**
The way I call these functions is like this:

```
getPlaylists(access_token)
      .then(playlists => Promise.all(playlists.map(playlist =>
        getArtists(playlist, access_token)))
      .then(artists => {

        artists.map(artist => {
          artist.map(a => {
            console.log(a);
            let component = renderToString(
                <App>
                    <Table artists={a} />
                </App>
            );

            res.send(
              component
            )
          })


        })

      }));
```

It only returns the first result - obviously because it only gets to loop through the forEach loop once, before "res.send()", so how do I make sure that it loops through all artists, before I render the view? I believe I have to do another Promise.all(), but I am not sure where - does anyone have an idea?

I appreciate it :)

Comment: I still didn't figure out what could be the solution for your question, but what I can say right now is that you aren't returning anything inside `artist.map()` function. Also, I didn't see what is `key` in `array.push(obj[key])`.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to remove the variable key from testing. I believe I have to do another Promise.all somewhere to get my artist images right?

Comment: Can you explain the data and it's structure? Because telling by your code it's quite confusing. `getArtists` for example seems to return a  *(Promise of)* Arrays of Arrays of Artists whereas `getArtistImages` returns an `img`? holding an *(optional)* images Array wich contains the actual images

Comment: It's hard to test without the actual data, but it seems that `getArtistsImages()` return just on element (or you're dealing like so). Also, the first `Promise.all()` is wrapping to much, I think. I think you would need another `Promise.all()` surrounding `artists.map()` to wait for every artist to be populated.

Comment: Hi, please check edits - wrapped artist.map in a Promise.all

Comment: "*the way that I retrieve the data from these promises*" - you're already doing it correctly with `playlists`, `artists` and `res`, so what's the problem?

Comment: How do I pass the data to the template? Do I just do "res.send()" inside the chain?

Comment: Please check new edit, I believe I am on to something :)

Comment: You seem to want to pass an array of results to  `res.send` - so don't call it within the `map`s, but call it with the return value of the `map`pings

Comment: @Bergi, yes exactly! how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Its old post but I think it can be helpfull for someone.

I wrote a plugin to perform foreach based on promises supporting concurrency. I see you dont need concurrency what turn things more simple to apply other solutions.

I wrote a code by your code using my plugin. It works!

```
'use strict';

var request = require('request')
var promiseForeach = require('promise-foreach')

function getPlaylists(access_token) {

    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
        json: true
    };

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
            var playlists = body.items;
            var playlistArray = [];
            playlists.forEach(function (playlist) {
                var name = playlist.name;
                var url = playlist.tracks.href;
                playlistArray.push(url);
            });
            if (!error) {
                resolve(playlistArray);
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });

    });
}

function getArtists(url, access_token) {

    var params = {
        url: url,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
        json: true
    };

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        request.get(params, function (error, response, body) {

            var tracks = body.items;
            var artistArray = [];
            tracks.forEach(function (artists) {
                let allArtists = artists.track.artists;
                allArtists.forEach(function (artist) {
                    artistArray.push(artist);
                });
            })

            if (!error) {

                promiseForeach.each(artistArray,
                    [function (artist) {
                        return getArtistImages(artist.id)
                    }],
                    function (arrayOfResultOfTask, currentList) {
                        return {
                            artistId: currentList.id,
                            artistName: currentList.name,
                            artistImages: arrayOfResultOfTask[0].images
                        }
                    },
                    function (err, newList) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err)
                            return;
                        }
                        resolve(newList)
                    })

            } else {
                reject(error);
            }

        });

    })

}

function getArtistImages(artistId) {
    var options = {
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + artistId,
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
        json: true
    };

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error != null) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(body);
            }
        });
    })

}

var access_token = 'YOUR-TOKEN';


getPlaylists(access_token)
    .then(playlists => {

        promiseForeach.each(playlists,
            [function (playlist) {
                return getArtists(playlist, access_token)
            }],
            function (arrayOfResultOfTask, currentList) {
                return {
                    playlistURL: currentList,
                    artist: arrayOfResultOfTask[0]
                }
                //return renderToString(
                //    <App>
                //        <Table artists={render} />
                //    </App>
                //);
            },
            function (err, newList) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                    return;
                }
                res.send(newList)
            })

    });
```

The plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-foreach

I hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, it sounds like you are tripping up on how to actually use the result of `Promises`.

**Asynchronous applications:**

`Promises` encapsulate an asynchronous result, which is made available through the callback passed to `then()`.

*This asynchronous-ism will cascade throughout your application.*

There are a number of ways applications manage the reality of asynchronous results: events, callbacks, observables, promises...

**Example (using events):**

This is a crude and untested example of how the data from an asynchronous request can get injected into your view. When my asynchronous request calls my `then()` callback, I update my model which triggers an event to re-render my view.

There are totally issues with this example (i.e. what if I don't want to rerender my whole view? what if my getArtists() returns sooner than my view can render it's loading state?). But for simplicity, we won't go there.

```
+function(){


    var _view = $('#viewport');
    var _model = {...}
    var _spotifyClient = new SpotifyClient(); // this contains method similar to those you included in your question

    _view.on('load', onLoad);
    _view.on('model:update', onModelUpdate);

    function onLoad() {
       _spotifyClient
         .getArtists()
         .then(function(result) {
           // when the getArtists() request has responded, I can update my model.
           updateModel({ isLoading: false, artists: result });
         })        

       // this will happen immediately after starting the "getArtists()" request.
       udpateModel({ isLoading: true });
    }

    function updateModel(mod) {
       for(var p in mod) {
          _model[p] = mod[p];
       }
       _view.trigger('model:update', _model);
    }        

    function onModelUpdate(model) {
       refreshView();
    }

    function refreshView() {
       var viewModel = buildTemplateModel(_model);
       renderTemplate(_view, viewModel);
    }

}();
```

I encourage you to research some view frameworks such as angular, knockout, or react. I also encourage you to research Reactive Extensions which provides an observable interface and many utilities regarding asynchronous streams.

**Note on side effects:**

Having the result of a promise trigger an event can be classified as a "side-effect". You should keep side-effects to a minimum in our application, and they really only belong in the controller / main part of your application.

If you are using promises in your application, reusable library classes and functions, that operate on promises, should return promises.

Comment: Yes, I haven't really wrapped my head around promises yet, I guess :) Please check new edit, I think I am almost there

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `res.send` on the array of all results, not on each one separately:

```
getPlaylists(access_token).then(playlists =>
    Promise.all(playlists.map(playlist =>
        getArtists(playlist, access_token)
    ))
).then(artists => {
    res.send(artists.map(artist =>
        artist.map(a => {
            console.log(a);
            return renderToString(
                <App>
                    <Table artists={a} />
                </App>
            );
        })
    ))
});
```

Also your parenthesis were slightly misnested (didn't match the indentation of the `then` calls) but that didn't lead to the problem.

Comment: Hi there, hm, it returns an array of html - very weird.

Comment: uh, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I want exactly what you said about returning an array of all results. However, this returns an array of the whole page: like this: "<html data-reactroot="" data-reactid="1" data-react-checksum="-1108652163"><head data-reactid="2"><meta name="viewport".... etc.

Comment: @MathiasLund I don't know what exactly `renderToString` does and what your `App` and `Table` components do, but those are responsible for creating the single results in the array.